# Is Wikipedia's read-write lock implementation correct?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, mutex

I was implementing a **write-preferring** R/W lock in C with SDL threads and a mutex. I [checked Wikipedia for a pseudo-code implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock#Using_a_condition_variable_and_a_mutex):

---

Input to both Reader and Writer: mutex mu, condition variable cond, integer readersWaiting=0 and boolean writerWaiting=false.

> Reader:
>
> - Lock mu
> - While writerWaiting is true:
>
>   - wait cond, mu[a]
> - Increment readersWaiting
> - Read operation
> - Decrement readersWaiting
> - While readersWaiting > 0:
>
>   - wait cond, mu
> - Notify cond (signal)
> - Unlock mu

---

> Writer:
>
> - Lock mu
> - While writerWaiting is true:
>
>   - wait cond, mu
> - Write operation
> - Set writerWaiting to true
> - While readersWaiting > 0:
>
>   - wait cond, mu
> - Set writerWaiting to false
> - Notify cond (broadcast)
> - Unlock mu

I believe that SDL satisfies this requirement

> wait: This is the standard "wait" operation on condition variables, which, among other actions, releases the mutex m

My question is, is this correct? Because I tried this with one consumer thread and both a single and multiple producer thread(s), and it didn't didn't work; the consumer would block and the queue wouldn't empty. I'm pretty sure that my implementation was the same as the pseudo code, but I ended up coming up with my own system instead.

Thinking about it now, it might be because of how my read operation handled an empty queue.

Additionally, can somebody explain what this sentence from the article means?

> Each of lock-for-read and lock-for-write has its own inverse operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is horribly broken in many ways. I'll just point out the most obvious: Readers do their reading while holding the lock. So there's no way it can even support multiple concurrent readers!

Given that it fails to actually even be a readers/writer lock at all, analyzing its other problems seems pretty pointless. Unsurprisingly, it also fails to prefer writers since a writer can't set `writerWaiting` to true until there are no readers.

By the way, the two mutex implementation on that page is horribly broken as well. **sigh**

Comment: While waiting the mutex is unlocked, but relocked when the thread is signalled, which in my case I believe it should be, since reading removes an element from the queue and I only want a single read thread but multiple writers.

Comment: @LegendofPedro The problem is not while waiting, it's while *reading*. The mutex is held while reading, so the code won't support multiple readers. So it's *not* a reader/writer lock. It's a "one thread at a time" lock, which is called a mutex. If you only have one reader, why not just use a mutex? The purpose of a reader/writer lock is to let more than one reader in at a time.

Comment: OK. I don't have a formal programming education so I don't know the right terminology and obviously studying Wikipedia isn't helping me! I did implement a solution which works for me, using a mutex and cond, setting the reader thread priority to low. I just want to learn how it should be done (and edit that article). Confirmation that the psuedo code wouldn't work is immensely helpful.